# GitHub Actions repository secret not passed correctly to re-usable workflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions repository secret that I am able to use to authenticate into GCP. This works as expected when I use the secret within a workflow in the same repository as the secret. For example this workflow runs successfully:

```
name: Auth to Google Cloud

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    env:
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT: 'some-account.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - id: auth
      name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
      uses: google-github-actions/auth@v1
      with:
          service_account: $SERVICE_ACCOUNT
          credentials_json:  ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}
```

However, when I try to accomplish the same via a re-usable workflow as described in the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-inputs-and-secrets-in-a-reusable-workflow), the `auth` step within the re-usable workflow fails with the following:

```
Error: google-github-actions/auth failed with: retry function failed after 1 attempt: failed to parse service account key JSON credentials: unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
```

Here is my caller workflow:

```
name: Re-usable Demo

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  call-reusable-workflow:
    uses: my-organization/reusable-workflows/.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml@master
    with:
      service-account: 'some-account.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
    secrets:
      gcp-sa-key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY  }}
```

Here is the re-usable workflow itself (in a different repo):

```
name: Re-usable Workflow

on: 
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      service-account:
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:
      gcp-sa-key:
        required: true

jobs:
  build:
    env:
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT:  ${{ inputs.service-account }}
        GCP_SA_KEY:  ${{ secrets.gcp-sa-key }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - id: auth
      name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
      uses: google-github-actions/auth@v1
      with:
          service_account: $SERVICE_ACCOUNT
          credentials_json: $GCP_SA_KEY
```

Note that the service account is passed correctly. I printed it in the re-usable workflow. Only the secret is not working. How can I fix this?

I have tried passing it as input, as well as using it directly without creating a variable for it, both to no avail.

Comment: How do you determine that it doesn't work? One potential issue is that you rely on parameter expansion inside of the `google-github-actions/auth` action; YAML doesn't expand anything for you. Did you try `credentials_json: ${{ env.GCP_SA_KEY }}` instead? (At which point you can just use `${{ secrets.gcp-sa-key }}` directly instead.)

Comment: @BenjaminW. well it was failing with the error within the 'auth' step with the message I put above so clearly it was not working, however it looks that using `credentials_json: ${{ env.GCP_SA_KEY }}` instead of   `credentials_json: $GCP_SA_KEY`  or  `credentials_json: ${{ secrets.gcp-sa-key }}`  does work! I don't really understand why though so feel free to create an answer explaining in more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use

```yaml
env:
  GCP_SA_KEY: ${{ secrets.gcp-sa-key }}
with:
  credentials_json: $GCP_SA_KEY
```

then GitHub Actions doesn't expand anything for you, but assigns the literal string `$GCP_SA_KEY` to the `credentials_json` input.

Now, if this is later used in a shell script, it might be expanded and imply that variables are always expanded – but we just don't know (and shouldn't rely on it).<sup>1</sup>

You could use an expression that accesses the value in the environment:

```yaml
env:
  GCP_SA_KEY: ${{ secrets.gcp-sa-key }}
with:
  credentials_json: ${{ env.GCP_SA_KEY }}
```

Now, the Actions runner does the expansion before the action ever gets to see the value.

At this point, there's no value in even assigning it to an environment variable first (unless the action relies on it specific values in the environment, of course), so you can simplify to

```yaml
with:
  credentials_json: ${{ secrets.gcp-sa-key }}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> More precisely, if it works, it's actually a sign that the action is vulnerable to [shell injection](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#understanding-the-risk-of-script-injections).